# Collision detection with a List

Tags: c#, xna

I got a list of enemies called objects and a list of bullets.

```
private List<enemyObjects> objects = new List<enemyObjects>();
```

The  `list`  objects is in the Game1 class.

I add and delete enemies in the list with this method:

```
public void LoadEnemies() {
        int Y = 100;
        if (spawn >= 1) 
        {
            spawn = 0;
            if (objects.Count() < 4)
                objects.Add(new enemyObjects(Content.Load<Texture2D>("obstacle"), new Vector2(1100, Y)));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!objects[i].isVisible)
            {
                //If the enemy is out of the screen delete it
                objects.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I also got a list of bullets: `public List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();`

The method where I fire the bullets:

```
private void ShootFireBall() {
        if (mCurrentState == State.Walking)
        {
            bool aCreateNew = true;
            foreach (Bullet aBullet in bullets)
            {
                if (aBullet.bulletVisible == false)
                {
                    aCreateNew = false;
                    aBullet.Fire(position + new Vector2(Size.Width / 2, Size.Height / 2),
                        new Vector2(200, 0), new Vector2(1, 0));
                }
            }

            if (aCreateNew)
            {
                Bullet aBullet = new Bullet();
                aBullet.LoadContent(contentManager, "bullet");
                aBullet.Fire(position + new Vector2(Size.Width / 2, Size.Height / 2),
                       new Vector2(200, 0), new Vector2(1, 0));
                bullets.Add(aBullet);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I need a rectangle, so I can check if there is a collision.
How can I check collision with 2 lists?
Is there any way to convert it to a Rectangle?
Been stuck on this for a few hours and really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have all of my sprites derive from a common type. Sprite, GameEntity, whatever. That base type would expose properties like `Bounds`, `Location`, etc.

Something like:

```
public abstract class Sprite
{
    public Vector2 Location { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)Location.X, (int)Location.Y, 
                                 _texture.Width, _texture.Height);
        }
    }

    private Texture2D _texture;

    public Sprite(Texute2D texture)
    {
        _texture = texture;
    }
}

public class enemyObjects : Sprite
{

    // enemy-specific properties go here

    public enemyObjects(Texture2D texture)
        : base(texture)
    {
    }
}

public class Bullet : Sprite
{

    // Bullet-specific properties go here

    public Bullet(Texture2D texture)
        : base(texture)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you could simply use `objects[i].Bounds` to get a rectangle that contains the object.